# Django - runserver error- value error: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, django

I just started learning django and I was trying out some tutorials online. Please help. This is just a small web app the accepts user input and displays it on the message board.

I am using windows and django 1.11.7. I use sublime text editor for python.

I am not sure whAt the error means. If somebody could help, it would be of great help. This is the error that I got:

```
`  Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
     at 0x03BF8F18>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", l
    ine 228, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\command
    s\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py
    ", line 359, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py
    ", line 346, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py
    ", line 81, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", l
    ine 16, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", l
    ine 26, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", lin
    e 254, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", l
    ine 35, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", lin
    e 405, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", l
    ine 35, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", lin
    e 398, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_
    module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\mb_project\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
        url(r'^', include('message_app.urls')),
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py",
     line 50, in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "C:\dev\message_board\mb\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_
    module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`
```

This is the file that it shows error:

```
`# mb_project/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('message_app.urls')),
]`
```

This is the message_app/urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import Home_page_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Home_page_view.as_view()),
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you check your last code block: there appear to be erroneous backticks around the code, as well as that the first line shouldn't be part of the code (but rather indicate the filename)

Comment: Given the traceback, the file with the null byte(s) is likely `message_app/urls.py`, not the one you show.

Comment: @Evert Hi. I have included that file too now.

Comment: If there is a hidden null byte, it likely won't be visible here on StackOverflow. Try running your Python executable on both `urls.py` files, just to see if they compile.

Comment: Hi, Have you a solution for your problem? Could you pls share caz I have the same problem. Thanks.